# Is it possible to install unixODBC driver for SQL server without root permission

Tags: sql-server, r, rodbc, unixodbc

I am trying to run the RODBC packages for the R programming language on our computer cluster.
For this purpose I have downloaded and installed [unixODBC](http://www.unixodbc.org/download.html) in my home folder (following some helpful instructions [here](https://carlo-hamalainen.net/blog/2012/5/11/r-makeflags-rpath-and-building-packages))

Now I realize that the necessary ODBC drivers for SQL server are not included, but in trying to download and install such drivers I encounter the problem that they all require root privileges which I do not have.

Is there a way to get a SQL server unixODBC driver installed without root privileges?

Our system is:

```
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)
```

I have looked at the drivers available from [Devart](https://www.devart.com/odbc/sqlserver/download.html) and [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568454(v=sql.110).aspx) so far.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason why I would expect you would specifically need root access is to edit the odbc.ini files. You can either build your own copy of unixODBC with prefix and/or sysconf set to a reachable location. Or set the ODBCSYSINI env variable to tell the driver manager to use $ODBCSYSINI/odbc.ini and $ODBCSYSINI/odbcinst.ini

The Easysoft driver can certainly be installed by non root, just set $EASYSOFT_ROOT to point to the alternative to /usr/local/easysoft

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but I just spent a lot of time figuring out the solution to a similar problem. If the SQL Server ODBC driver is not available perhaps you can use FreeTDS. This was available in our Linux (whereas the other SQL Server ODBC drivers were not). It did the trick. To find out what ODBC drivers are available to you (and where they are) run the linux command:

```
odbcinst -j
```

To use FreeTDS you should modify the local .odbc.ini file with your settings. Here's what's in my .odbc.ini for an example:

```
[DB_NAME]
Driver=FreeTDS
Description=Microsoft SQL Server 2016
Server=address.of.your.server
Database=DB_NAME
Port=1433
TDS_Version=7.4
UseDeclareFetch
```

Once I did this, then I could connect to SQL Server. (I am using Python but I bet a similar approach would work for R.)

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Thanks @datacathy! I did not know we have a local one for the user to edit!